# How to connect android project with php files which is saved outside the workspace?

Tags: php, android, eclipse, xampp, workspace

Is it possible to connect an Android project (developed using Eclipse Indigo) to PHP files that are saved outside the workspace?

I am using Xampp server and saved it under htdocs. But I couldn't connect Eclipse to it.

I am not using PDT. If I have to install any plugin .plz say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make calls to PHP pages using the URL class from Android. This question will help you [Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

Comment: Thanks Tom!! Can you help me a little more by saying that - how to connect to local host? How to build path with my xampp files?

Comment: htdocs in the xampp folder is your root. so httP://127.0.0.1/abc/test.php would be the file "test.php" in the folder C://xampp/htdocs/abc